# Prolog Maze: Sorting list of list with condition

Tags: prolog, maze

I have a question about my Prolog project.
It's a maze and I want to sort a given list of list by distance.

So, they give:

```
order_poss(PossiblePositions, PossOrd, InitialPosition, FinalPosition)

?- order_poss([ (c, 4, 4), (d, 5, 5)], PossOrd, (1, 6), (5, 6)).
PossOrd = [ (d, 5, 5), (c, 4, 4)].
```

I need to sort by distance from the shortest distance between PossiblePositions and FinalPosition.
If equal, sort by longest distance between PossiblePositions and InitialPosition.

Distance I made:

```
distance((L1, C1), (L2, C2), Dist) :-
   Dist is abs(L1 - L2) + abs(C1 - C2)
```

Thanks

Comment: Keep an eye on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080561/prolog-sort-a-list-of-tuples). It appears to be the same assignment.

Comment: Oh. Yes it is. But it doesn't have any answer.

Comment: That's why I said to keep an eye on it. Then you need to make an attempt at something. It's a poorly formed question here on SO to post an assignment and ask for help without showing some effort. The link I gave shows a tiny bit of effort, which is probably why it doesn't have an answer. But an answer may appear at some point.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that. I made an attempt already. Will post it.

Comment: The online help here has a section about "How to ask a good question" which is worth reading.